# Gmail API Mail Insert In Gmail Using PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail-api

I'm trying to insert email in gmail Using google gmail API But somehow mail going to be bounce. any one can please help me on this. Here is the code which I am using. Is there anything which i'm missing

```
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET_ID');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/demo/google/test/');



    $accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
    $client->refreshToken($accessToken );

    / set mesaage /
   // $raw_message = "To:test@gmail.com <test905@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $raw_message = "To:test@gmail.com <testfirstlastname009@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $raw_message .= "From:dev2test.@gmail.com <dev2test@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $raw_message .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' .base64_encode('Repoting from the crm task') . "?=\r\n";

// Set the right MIME & Content type
    $raw_message .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $raw_message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    //$raw_message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";

   /* $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($raw_message), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $message->setRaw($mime);*/

    $template = "Hello this is <br> testing email for the localsystem sending by gmail or not";
    $raw_message .= $template;
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($raw_message), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $message->setRaw($mime);
    /* end of set message*/

    $gmailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

    try {
        $messages = $gmailService->users_messages->insert('me',$message);
        print 'Message with ID: ' . $messages->getId() . ' sent.';
        exit;     
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: did you enable https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @Saveen Thanks Yes that is enable. and I am also getting some message Id but it is same all time. When I tried to insert email.  Can you please help now.

Comment: @DalmTo can you look into this.